# Require.js continues to load uncompressed modules after optimization

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, r.js

I've run the r.js optimizer and it seems to be working properly. The only trouble I'm having is that while the compressed optimized version loads it continues to load all the uncompressed modules. Any reason why this would happen?

[image]
build.js

```
{
appDir: '../static',
mainConfigFile: '../static/javascript/config.js',
dir: '../public',
baseUrl: 'javascript/libs',
useStrict: false,
wrap: false,
optimizeCss: "standard",
optimize: "uglify2",
generateSourceMaps: false,
preserveLicenseComments: false,
uglify2: {
    "screw-ie8": true,
    warnings: false,
    mangle: true
},
throwWhen: {
    optimize: true
},
pragmasOnSave: {},
modules: [

    {
        name: '../front',
        include: ['views/front/main'],
        exclude: ['../config']
    }

    ,

    {
        name: '../portal',
        include:  ['views/portal/main'],
        exclude: ['../config']
    }

    ,

    {
        name: '../survey',
        include:  ['views/survey/main'],
        exclude: ['../config']

    }

]
}
```

config.js

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/javascript/libs',
  urlArgs: 'v=' + (new Date()).getTime(),
  enforceDefine: false,
  paths: {
    collections: '../collections',
    etc: '../etc',
    models: '../models',
    views: '../views',
    templates: '../../templates',
    backbone: 'backbone',
    underscore: 'lodash',
    'underscore.string': 'underscore.string',
  },
  shim: {
    backbone: {
      deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    underscore: {
      deps: ['jquery', 'underscore.string'],
      exports: '_'
    },
  }
});
```

The config is loaded like so:

```
<script data-main="/javascript/portal-v2.0.0.js" src="/javascript/libs/require.js"></script>
```

and portal.js looks like this:

```
require(['./config'], function() {
  return require(['views/portal/main']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You start loading your application with this:

```
<script data-main="/javascript/portal-v2.0.0.js" src="/javascript/libs/require.js"></script>
```

What this does is schedule the loading of your `portal-v2.0.0.js` file. However, its actual loading happens at some indeterminate point in the future. (By the way, you should not put the `.js` at the end of module names. The value of `data-main` is a module name, so no `.js` there. It can cause subtle problems.)

As evidenced by the loading patterns you get, by the time the following code executes, the above module has not loaded:

```
require(['./config'], function() {
  return require(['views/portal/main']);
});
```

When RequireJS gets to `require(['views/portal/main'])`, it finds and loads the individual module instead of the bundle.

The solution here would be to add the following to your runtime configuration:

```
bundles: {
    '/javascript/portal-v2.0.0': ['views/portal/main'],
}
```

This tells RequireJS that when you require the module named `views/portal/main`, it should look for it in the same place where the module named `/javascript/portal-v2.0.0` is located. (And remember to remove the `.js` extension from your `data-main`.) You do **not** need to list all the modules that are in `portal-v2.0.0` there, only those that you are requiring from *outside* `portal-v2.0.0`. Note that the same would be true for your other bundles if any of their modules are required *outside* of them, you must list these modules in appropriate `bundles` settings.

You should also look into `removeCombined` to remove the individual files from the output directory and only keep your optimized bundles.

Comment: Thanks Louis, I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes.